# Send an SMS for a cloudwatch Alarm outside of us-east?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

It looks like AWS does not provide SMS as a protocol for SNS topic subscribers outside of US East. I wanted to hook up my CloudWatch alarms and receive text messages when something breaks but cannot send them to SMS.

Answer (score 10):

**YES!**

After some digging I was able to get this to work. It's a little more complicated than just selecting a topic or inputing an alarm but it works great!

**The key to the solution was using AWS's lambda functions!**

The flow of data is such:

```
> Alarm triggered
>  -> Push notification to SNS
>  -> SNS posts to lambda
>  -> lambda reposts to SNS on us-east-1
>  -> subscriber receives message
```

Just the services:

```
> CloudWatch Alarm   (us-west-2) 
>  -> SNS            (us-west-2) 
>  -> Lambda         (us-west-2)
>  -> SNS            (us-east-1)
>  -> SMS subscriber (us-east-1)
```

I won't talk too much about setting up SNS or setting up lambda, you can go through the examples that already exist for that. However, I will share the lambda code that I wrote to perform this. You can test it by using the publish message to topic functionality.

```
console.log('Loading function');

var Aws = require('aws-sdk');

var usEastSns = new Aws.SNS({
    accessKeyId: "ENTER YOUR ACCESS KEY HERE",
    secretAccessKey: "ENTER YOUR SECRET KEY HERE",
    region: "us-east-1",
    logger: console
});

exports.snsProxy = function(event, context) {
    var message = event.Records[0].Sns;
    console.log("received message: ", message);
    var newMessage = buildNewMessage(message);
    console.log("publishing: ", newMessage);
    usEastSns.publish(newMessage, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        } else {
            // It's important that we succeed in the callback
            // otherwise it seems to succeed without sending
            console.log(data);           
            context.succeed(message);    
        }
    })
};

function buildNewMessage(message) {
    // For some reason the message that gets sent in the event
    // does not contain the same interface as what the library
    // expects so it needs to be created
    return {
        TargetArn: "ENTER YOUR ARN IN US EAST HERE",
        Message: message.Message,
        Subject: message.Subject,
        MessageAttributes: collectAttr(message.MessageAttributes)
    };
}

function collectAttr(attrs) {
    var newAttrs = {};
    for (var attr in attrs) {
        newAttrs[attr] ={
            DataType: attrs[attr].Type,
            StringValue: attrs[attr].Value
        }
    }
    return newAttrs;
}
```

This doesn't require any additional libraries other than the aws-sdk that is already in the lambda function. You can feel free to leave out the console logging if you don't want it but it was useful for debugging.

*If you use there test functionality, it will likely fail. I believe this is because the callback never happens.*

Remember that the lambda should not be on us-east-1 since it will be triggered on whatever region you are using.

**Links to tutorials:**

SNS Publish api:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property

How to node.js in lambda:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html

A really great tutorial on using other aws functions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more modern/concise similar solution leveraging the new Node 8.10 an environment variable:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const TARGET_ARN = process.env.TARGET_ARN;
var sns = new AWS.SNS({
    region: "us-east-1"
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const message = event.Records[0].Sns;
    return await forwardMessage(message);
};

function forwardMessage(message) {
    const messageToForward = {
        TargetArn: TARGET_ARN,
        Message: message.Message,
        Subject: message.Subject
    };

    return sns.publish(messageToForward).promise();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Outside of us-east-1 you will not find any protocol like SMS in the protocols dropdown

[image: Subscription Creation under SNS]

**AWS is not providing a proper solution but you can do some hacks for this**

To implement this Solution I am using **AWS Lambda** but if you are having some HTTP endpoint(any sort of API) then you can also use it, the basic steps are same.

- Create a **Topic** under the SNS section
- Create a **Subscription** and attach the subscription to the Topic created in point 1
- Go to Lambda service and create a Lambda like below

```
import json
import boto3
import os


ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("ACCESS_KEY", "<your key>")
ACCESS_SECRET = os.environ.get("ACCESS_SECRET", "<your-secret>")
AWS_REGION = os.environ.get("AWS_REGION_NAME", "<your-regoin>")

def execute_sms_service(event, context):
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
    alarm_description = message['AlarmDescription']

    recipient_numbers = [<recipient number list>]
    sender_id = <sender_id>
    message = 'Alarm Name: {}\nAlarm Description:{}\n\n '.format(alarm_name, alarm_description)

    sns = boto3.client('sns', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                   aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET,
                   region_name=AWS_REGION)
    for number in recipient_numbers:
        response = sns.publish(
            PhoneNumber=number,
            Message=message,
            MessageAttributes={
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {'DataType': 'String',
                                     'StringValue': sender_id},
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {'DataType': 'String',
                                    'StringValue': 'Promotional'}
            }
        )
        print(response)
```

- After creating the AWS Lambda check the lambda is working properly or not then attach this lambda in the Subscription protocol created in the second point.
- Create an **Alarm** and configure the action to send the notification to the Topic created in first point

Hope this helps, and please comment if there is some doubt on the above procedure.