# How to set AWS SNS SMS notification from Mumbai Region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS does not support for SMS service in Mumbai region. but I need to do this , when I try to create cloud watch alarm in send notification settings i copied the ARN of SNS topic which is in virginia but it show the error message **something went wrong** , is there any way to do the same please share your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it. CloudWatch will only publish to SNS topics that are in the same region as your cloudwatch alerts/alarms.

But you can have a workaround similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645319/1562662)

Similar to the solution, you can create the following resources:

```
> CloudWatch Alarm   (ap-south-1) 
>  -> SNS            (ap-south-1) 
>  -> Lambda         (you can have this in any region, cross region lambda can be invoked from sns)
>  -> SNS            (us-east-1), invoked from lambda
>  -> SMS subscriber (us-east-1)
```

**UPDATE**

AWS confirms this is not possible https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=130530.

Verified that it's still not possible to publish to SNS topics in another region. I tried to create a CW alarm in ap-south-1 to send alerts in a topic in us-east-1, 
`[ec2-user@ip-**** ~]$ aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name TestSMSAlarm --alarm-description "Test Alarm turned ON" --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:*****:Test --metric-name HealthyHostCount --namespace AWS/ELB --statistic Maximum --dimensions "Name=LoadBalancerName,Value=awseb-e-z-AWSEBLoa-****" --period 300 --evaluation-periods 1 --threshold 1 --comparison-operator LessThanThreshold --region ap-south-1`

and below error is what I got:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutMetricAlarm operation: Invalid region us-east-1 specified. Only ap-south-1 is supported.

SMS is now supported in below regions, from [SNS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/):

> Which AWS regions support Worldwide SMS?
>
> 1) US-East-1 (Virginia), 2) US-West-2 (Oregon), 3) EU-West-1 (Dublin), 4) Asia Pacific (Tokyo), 5) Asia Pacific (Singapore), and 6) Asia Pacific (Sydney).

Comment: so we can't access SNS ARN from another region ?

Comment: So any alternative for sending SMS to mobile numbers in Mumbai regions? If we send SMS from another region say Singapore to mobile in Mumbai what will be the charges ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe SNS pricing for SMS is dependent on the destination country and carrier. AWS [SMS pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/) page shows pricing per country and network. Enter the country where you want to send SMS to view the prices.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SNS now supports SMS text messaging in the Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region!

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/applications-using-amazon-sns-to-send-sms-can-now-be-hosted-in-the-asia-pacific-mumbai-and-europe-frankfurt-regions/